# Creating custom JList that runs method other than toString for Objects

Tags: java, jlist

In the game I'm trying to create, I have a class which displays the inventory for a character in a JList. I understand that populating a JList with Objects will cause the toString method for that object to run when the JList is actually displayed. I want to create a custom JList that does something other than run the toString method on the Objects populating it. I understand that I can overwrite the toString method on Objects, but I need the toString method to be different than what's displayed in the inventory. For some reason, I'm unable to view classes such as Object or JList (I can still view my own), otherwise I'd look through the code myself. (TL;DR - I need to overwrite the method in JList that runs toString on the objects populating it)

Side note: only a specific type of Object will be put into the JList, so I know what I intend to run instead of toString, and the custom JList will only be used in 1 class.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is with [`ListModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html). For details, read [the official tutorial on How to Use Lists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). Pay close attention to the section on [Creating a ListModel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#creating).

Comment: I was unsure of where it was handled - I'll have to try that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe simplest way is to make a sub class from `JList` - a new class extends JList - and add the method(s) you need and use it instead of `JList` .

Comment: My only problem with this is that I'm unsure of what process it goes through. When elements are actually displayed, I'd imagine it runs through and displays the text returned by toString() on the objects. But, in the case that that is a specific method unto its own, that's the method that would need to be overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer for myself. A custom class must be written extending JLabel implementing ListCellRenderer<>. In this, you can specify exactly what goes into the text component of each cell in the JList.